# Angular select ngChange get the parent json object key not the value

Tags: angularjs

I've created a hypothetical example; since i can't share my real example with you all. So forgive my hasty json file i created.

To the problem. Say i have a select populated like so using a json file which contains an array of (US State) objects:

**State.json**

```
{ "states": 
   [
        {
          code: "AL",
          name: "Alabama"
        },
        {
          code: "AK",
          name: "Alaska"
        },
        {
          code: "AS",
          name: "American Samoa"
        },
        {
          code: "AZ",
          name: "Arizona"
        },
        {
          code: "AR",
          name: "Arkansas"
        },
        {
          code: "CA",
          name: "California"
        },
        {
          code: "CO",
          name: "Colorado"
        },
        {
          code: "CT",
          name: "Connecticut"
        },
        ... etc...


]}
```

I pull in the json file and set it to a scope item like so:

**main-controller.js**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ('$scope') { 
  $scope.states = [
    { code: "AL": name: "Alabama" },
    //etc
  ];

  $scope.selectStateChange = function (stateCode) {
      console.log(stateCode);
  }
});
```

**index.html**

Here's my select:

```
<select ng-model="selectedState" ng-change="selectStateChange(selectedState)">
    <option ng-repeat="state in states">{{state.name}}</option>
</select>
```

#### My Problem

How does one get the actual state code to be passed into function selectStateChange on my ng-change?

Comment: Its not clear by the description above if your `$scope.states` is an object (hash) or an array.

Comment: Sorry it's an array of state objects. I've updated it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try using [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) instead of a ng-repeat on options.

This way your model will be up to date and it will be quite convenient to access the selected object.

It should looks like this in your case :

```
<select ng-model="selectedState" ng-options="state.name for state in states" ng-change="selectStateChange()">
</select>
```

and your JS should display your object:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ('$scope') { 
  $scope.states = { "AL": "Alabama",  //etc }
  $scope.selectedState = null;

  $scope.selectStateChange = function () {
      console.log(selectedState);
  }
});
```

This way, selectedState is equal to {
          code: "AL",
          name: "Alabama"
        }

Comment: Sorry made few updates after sending, had some errors.

Comment: Are you intentionally not passing anything in your selectStateChange function?

Comment: Yes you can access the model from ng-model and so in your scope

Answer (score 0):

What get's logged into the console by console.log(stateCode);?

Did you try

```
  $scope.selectStateChange = function (selectedState) {
      console.log(selectedState.code);
  }
```

Comment: `undefined` selected state returns the state.name

Comment: @chrisjlee I suggest following sebastienbarbier answer